# bash: xport: command not found

Tags: bash, profile

I have used `export` to change my `PATH variable`. `export` not `xport`, but now every time I open a terminal I get this error:

```
bash: xport: command not found
[mirko@localhost ~]$
```

I tried removing everything I have added in `~/.bashrc`, even replacing it with one from `/etc/skel`. I didn't touched `~/.bash_profile` or any other file for this purpose.

Comment: Some systems have a `/etc/profile.d` did you check there?

Comment: There is a list of some files in it, but not export anywhere.

Comment: I think it's cached somewhere. Rebooting doesn't help.

Comment: Please put output of your .rc file

Comment: `. bashrc`  -   http://pastebin.com/7UL6eAYT
`.bash_profile`   -   http://pastebin.com/JnaNHKA8

Comment: `/etc/bashrc`   -   http://pastebin.com/bLr902mm

Comment: When I run `source ~/.bashrc` I also get same thing.

Comment: What error do you get? Please quote it precisely.

Comment: `bash: xport: command not found
[mirko@localhost ~]$ `

This is all I get when open terminal.

Comment: I'm guessing you accidentally somehow introduced a unicode character into the file.

Comment: Start a subshell with `bash -l -x` and see where execution fails. With `-x` you'll get a line of output for every command bash eXecutes. You should be able to use that to pinpoint the malformed "export". Delete that line, and re-type it in manully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To possibly aid you in hunting down where the problem is, add the following to the top of your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files:

```
${BASH_DEBUG:+set -x}
${BASH_DEBUG:+trap 'echo ^^ Line: $LINENO ^^' DEBUG}
```

Then in a command shell, run :

```
BASH_DEBUG=1 bash -l
```

to start a login shell, which will use `.bash_profile`, or without the `-l` which will read `.bashrc`.

For each line read/processed, you'll get an output of the commands bash executed, and the line number.

Comment: Here's the output - http://pastebin.com/teHY7369

Comment: OK, so it's nothing in your local files. Now put that at the top of your `/etc/profile` and repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot `bash -l -x` helped me to find it. It was in `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`. There was `xport JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/`. Thanks to every one of you, especialy Otheus and elbarna.

Answer (score 0):

I see this line in bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

I will correct to

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Try and tell me

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: Try this last attempt. 1)Create a test user 2)Delete .bash_profile .profile .bashrc,and try to set a new bash_profile with your favorite environment(variables,aliases,etc),source .bash_profile. Must work

Comment: Why creating a new user? Can I just remove them and copy from /etc/skel?

Comment: Ok I tried. Error doesn't show up if i remove this if loop from `.bashrc`, or file itself. But then i dont see username in terminal now there's `bash-4.3$`.

Comment: From the other files copy one after one the variables,in this case you missing PS1,and don't forget to do source .modified_file